# How to link to other fns/structs/enums/traits in rustdoc?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I'm building a Rust library and want to give it some polish. In the rustdoc, I'd sometimes like to *link* to other parts of the library within the docs, e.g. `fn`s, `trait`s or `struct`s. What is the official syntax for this?

Comment: there has been some discussion here: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/rustdoc-link-to-other-types-from-doc-comments/968

Comment: and an open rfc here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/792

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[As of Rust 1.48, Rustdoc now supports direct intra-doc links.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504254/87234)

---

*Pre Rust 1.48:*

`Rustdoc` seems to generate mostly deterministic filenames for constituent elements of a crate. Therefore if you have an `enum` named `Complex` you can generally link to it using:

```
[Complex](enum.Complex.html)
```

Similarly a `struct` called `Point` would look like:

```
[Point](struct.Point.html)
```

This should carry over to most definitions (`fn`, `trait`, and so on).

For referencing elements of a crate at different nesting levels, you can use relative paths (where each module is its own folder):

```
[Point](../model/struct.Point.html)
```

or use absolute paths:

```
[Point](/crate_name/model/struct.Point.html)
```

More of these "conventions", including anchors for specific fields, etc., can be deduced if one builds docs (`cargo doc --no-deps --open`) and navigates to the field or item they want and takes note of the URL. Remember that only pub items are published to docs.

Comment: Relative paths work as well for objects in other modules: 
[Point](../point/struct.Point.html)

Comment: The URL `[Point](/crate_name/model/struct.Point.html)` seems not to work anymore, at least when I open docs on my filesystem. It links to `file:///crate_name/...`.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Though this still works, please see shepmaster's answer for an easier up-to-date approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504254/353178

Answer (score 104):

As of [Rust 1.48](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1480-2020-11-19), you can now rely on [RFC 1946](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1946-intra-rustdoc-links.html). This adds the concept of intra-documentation links. This allows using [Rust paths](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html) as the URL of a link:

> 1. `[Iterator](std::iter::Iterator)`
> 2. `[Iterator][iter]`, and somewhere else in the document: `[iter]: std::iter::Iterator`
> 3. `[Iterator]`, and somewhere else in the document: `[Iterator]: std::iter::Iterator`

The RFC also introduces ["Implied Shortcut Reference Links"](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1946-intra-rustdoc-links.html#implied-shortcut-reference-links). This allows leaving out the link reference, which is then inferred automatically.

> 1. `[std::iter::Iterator]`, without having a link reference definition for Iterator anywhere else in the document
> 2. `` [`std::iter::Iterator`] ``, without having a link reference definition for Iterator anywhere else in the document (same as previous style but with back ticks to format link as inline code)

---

As a concrete example, this source code:

```rust
//! Check out [ExampleStruct], especially [this
//! method](ExampleStruct::foo), but [the trait method][trait] is also
//! cool. There is also [an enum variant you can
//! use](nested::ExampleEnum::Beta).
//!
//! [trait]: ExampleTrait::bar

pub struct ExampleStruct;

impl ExampleStruct {
    pub fn foo(&self) {}
}

pub trait ExampleTrait {
    fn bar();
}

pub mod nested {
    pub enum ExampleEnum {
        Alpha,
        Beta,
    }
}
```

Produces this documentation:

[image: example generated documentation]

Specifically, this HTML is generated:

```html
<p>Check out <a href="../doc_link_example/struct.ExampleStruct.html" title="ExampleStruct">ExampleStruct</a>, especially <a href="../doc_link_example/struct.ExampleStruct.html#method.foo">this method</a>, but <a href="../doc_link_example/trait.ExampleTrait.html#tymethod.bar">the trait method</a> is also cool. There is also <a href="../doc_link_example/nested/enum.ExampleEnum.html#Beta.v">an enum variant you can use</a>.</p>
```

Comment: For absolute module paths, `[foo](crate::stuff::thing)` seems to work.

Comment: @rodrigocfd yes, that's [listed in the documentation I've linked](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#crate).

Comment: Is there a way to reference a different crate in the same workspace? E.g. I have a macros crate and the actual lib crate and I'd like to have a link from the documentation in the macros crate to the relevant code using the macro in the lib crate. In the macros crate, trying to link to `[my_lib_crate::module::Symbol]` warns of a broken link; trying `[../my_lib_crate::module::Symbol]` doesn't recognize this as a link. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: @OrenBen-Kiki I'd expect that you'd need to import the lib crate from the macros crate and then that would allow you to reference it.

Comment: Yes, one can have one-directional links this way if one crate uses another; but you can't have two-way links because that would cause a circular dependency between the crates. An option that works is for the lib crate to pub use the macros crate and re-export all the macros, and document everything in the lib crate. But there seems to be no way to freely link in both directions between two crates in a workspace...?

Comment: @OrenBen-Kiki sounds like you want https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74481. What I have done for my procedural macros is to re-export them from the library and document them there. Rustdoc combines the documentation in that case.

Comment: @Shepmaster - thanks for the link; yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Seems there's no solution for now other than re-exprting everything from the inner crate out of the outer one, or inserting links using manual (fragile) URLs.

Answer (score 10):

If one wants to link some specific part of a struct e.g., a method named `foo` in the same struct (using *stable* rust, not *nightly*)

```
[foo](#method.foo)
```

or if it is in another struct

```
[foo](struct.OtherStruct.html#method.foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rust **1.49 nightly** it works (1.48 stable not released yet):

- [`super::structs::WebApiResponse`]
- [`mycrate::structs::WebApiResponse`]

etc.

[Read here](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1946-intra-rustdoc-links.html)

Answer (score -1):

Since the documentation is written in Markdown, just use the Markdown syntax for Hyperlinks; i.e.

```
[anchor text](URL)
```

Also, take a look at this: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/documentation.html

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, because I don't think there's a way to figure out the URL.