# rustdoc link to enum variant

Tags: rust, enums, rustdoc

In rust, I want rustdoc text to link to an enum variant. What is the syntax for that?

#### Example

Given [rust code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6a4da0ba26193b1c8d875c7fb7c01712) residing at project file `src/common.rs`, (this rustdoc code failed to link)

```rust
/// your result!
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum MyResult<T, E> {
    /// this is good!
    Found(T),
    /// task completed!
    Done,
    /// this is bad!
    Err(E),
}

impl<T, E> MyResult<T, E> {
    /// Returns `true` if the result is [`Found`], [`Done`].
    ///
    /// In other words, this is not an [`Err`](Err)
    ///
    /// [Found]: self::MyResult::Found
    /// [Done]: self::Done
    /// [Err]: crate::common::MyResult::Err
    pub const fn is_ok(&self) -> bool {
        matches!(*self, MyResult::Found(_) | MyResult::Done)
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The rust docs are built with command:

```
cargo doc --locked --release --frozen --no-deps -v
```

#### Problem

In the generated rust docs, the various link anchors fail to link to the enum variants within `MyResult`.

The created doc looks like:

```
Returns true if the result is [Found], [Done].

In other words, this is not an Err
```

- The text `[Found]`, and `[Done]` fail to link.
- The text `Err` links to `https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/core/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Err`.
- I have also tried other variations of linking syntax like

  - `/// [Done]: MyResult#variant.Done`
  - `/// [Done]: self::MyResult#variant.Done`

---

How do I create rust doc intra-doc links to in-module `enum` variants?

Comment: Similar question [_How to link to other fns/structs/enums/traits in rustdoc?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582064/how-to-link-to-other-fns-structs-enums-traits-in-rustdoc)

Answer (score 3):

Use syntax form

```
/// [SomeVariant]: self::MyEnum#variant.SomeVariant
```

The question's example rustdoc code will have `#variant.` link anchor:

```rust
/// your result!
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum MyResult<T, E> {
    /// this is good!
    Found(T),
    /// task completed!
    Done,
    /// this is bad!
    Err(E),
}

impl<T, E> MyResult<T, E> {
    /// Returns `true` if the result is [`Found`], [`Done`].
    ///
    /// In other words, this is not an [`Err`]
    ///
    /// [`Found`]: self::MyResult#variant.Found
    /// [`Done`]: self::MyResult#variant.Done
    /// [`Err`]: self::MyResult#variant.Err
    pub const fn is_ok(&self) -> bool {
        matches!(*self, MyResult::Found(_) | MyResult::Done)
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

In the rustdoc output, clicking on the text `Found` then jumps to the definition for the enum variant `Found`.

Related, linking to methods is similar, use `#method.` link anchor:

```rust
/// [`MyStruct.my_method()`]: self::MyStruct#method.my_method
```